# How to render x-template using vue custom directives?

Tags: angularjs, vuejs2

I have an `angularjs` directive that I'm trying to replicate using `vuejs`:

Twig (project tag it's the original angularjs code):

```
<a class="animated fade-in-right" v-for="project in projects">
    <project project-on-delete="onDelete" project-show-delete-action="true" project-allow-delete="project.ownerId == user.id" project-show-progress="true" project-show-status="true"></project>
</a>
```

Then in the actual directive.js, another twig template was called, like this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'project.tpl.html',
```

That file is html inside a `script` tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="project.tpl.html">
  html
</script>
```

Now my question is how do I make the same, using the vue directive to render the `project.tpl.html` inside the `<project>`tag?

In case it wasn't very specific, I want this to happen:

```
<project>
  project.tpl.html
</project>
```

Comment: you can use props for that https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the `id` I gave; using `id="project-template` instead, solves my problem.
Probably some incompatibility with dots in id names.